# getting 403 Forrbiden from UPS

Tags: json, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, ups

I'm using ImportJSONViaPost function to grab FedEx tracking status to my Google doc. which is working. Trying to do the same for UPS and hit a bump with 403-Forrbiden.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Fedex

```
=INDEX(ImportJSONViaPost("https://www.fedex.com/trackingCal/track","data=%7B%22TrackPackagesRequest%22%3A%7B%22appType%22%3A%22WTRK%22%2C%22appDeviceType%22%3A%22DESKTOP%22%2C%22supportHTML%22%3Atrue%2C%22supportCurrentLocation%22%3Atrue%2C%22uniqueKey%22%3A%22%22%2C%22processingParameters%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22trackingInfoList%22%3A%5B%7B%22trackNumberInfo%22%3A%7B%22trackingNumber%22%3A%22"&123456789012&"%22%2C%22trackingQualifier%22%3A%22%22%2C%22trackingCarrier%22%3A%22%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D&action=trackpackages&locale=en_US&version=1&format=json",,"/TrackPackagesResponse/packageList/scanEventList,/TrackPackagesResponse/packageList/trackingCarrierDesc","noHeaders"),1,5)
```

UPS

```
=INDEX(ImportJSONViaPost("https://www.ups.com/track/api/Track/GetStatus?loc=en_CA","%7B%22Locale%22%3A%22en_CA%22%2C%22TrackingNumber%22%3A%5B%221ZA668990495524105%22%5D%2C%22Requester%22%3A%22%22%2C%22returnToValue%22%3A%22%22%7D",,"/trackDetails[0].packageStatus","noHeaders"),1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the 403 status and the presence of "api" in the URL, I wonder if you're trying to access the UPS API in a way that requires an Access Key. The [API Tech Support Guide](https://www.ups.com/assets/resources/media/en_US/ups-dev-kit-user-guide.pdf) walks nicely through the process for acquiring one.